# How to define an object in another layer?

Tags: python, game-engine

I have a second scene and using `scene2.objects["obj"]` isn't working. The object is is another layer, and I cannot figure out how to define it. I've defined "scene2," and there is no problem with that. How do I define objects in different layers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Layers are properties of the object see this snippet:

```
import bpy

# create layers vector with only one layer enabled
def layers(l):
    all = [False]*20
    all[l]=True
    return all

o = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
# set object to layer 2 only (layers from 0..19)
o.layers = layers(2)

# lookup scene by name 
scene = bpy.data.scenes["Scene2"]
# link object to scene
scene.objects.link(o)
```